# HTML to picture ( php parser for html2jpg / html2pic / html2img )

Tags: php, html, css, parsing

I need to make thumbnails from html (and css) code. Similar to flash's AIR1 HTMLLoader.

Is there a php class or php script that does that?

Comment: Probably not, you would need a full browser engine to not only parse the HTML but also render it correctly so you could make an image from it. AIR includes WebKit so it is able to render HTML directly.

Comment: @poke even primitive render?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "rendering an HTML page".  There are many tools out there that will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the command line from PHP (via `exec()` or `shell_exec()`) you can check out [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), a headless WebKit browser with a JavaScript API. I use this to do exactly what you're describing:

1. I generate an HTML file locally
2. I pass the path of that HTML file and an output path for the image (in my case a PNG) to a bash script that executes a call to PhantomJS (there are great examples when you download the package)
3. I serve up the generated image

I've tried a LOT of potential solutions and spent many hours on this problem and PhantomJS is by far the easiest I've found. There is a bit of lag waiting for the headless browser to start up, but from what I understand the latest version allows you to keep it running on a port of your choosing. I haven't been able to try this yet. You'll need GhostDriver for this as well. Check out the [1.8 Release Notes](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.8.html) for more info.

Good luck!

Comment: I see, that requires installation on local computer

Comment: Yes. You need to install it on your server and be able to make whatever scripts you run executable and have proper permissions. In a shared environment you'll probably be limited as far as this goes, but locally or any VPS or dedicated environment you should be fine. As far as I know there's really no other way to do what you're trying to do.